# Eclipse workspace directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to program in *C* using Eclipse and I am asked to give a workspace directory when I launch Eclipse. I read that the workspace is where you store your projects. But when I write a .c program and have its .exe file in the same place, I will want to have it in "Documents" or similar and not under C:\users\something. Will all my codes and files be stored there? How should I understand this workspace-directory question?

Sorry, I'm not used to this as I come from Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's workspace directory is where your projects are stored *during development*. So your main source code is here, but also all your doco, Eclipse config, test files, executables, etc.

When your project is complete and you are ready to deploy, you can put your executable wherever you want, eg. your "Documents" directory or `C:\Program Files`.

Responding to your comment, you can also put the source code (.c) wherever you want too. But it would be unusual to *deploy* source code.

Comment: When a project is complete. Will I be able to not only store the executable file wherever I want, but also the .c source code file?